# knockout js trying to use select inside foreach

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am a KO newbie and I am working on a small demo project to get going with KO. This is a small form which has questios and drop-down select answers, that users can choose from.

The HTML snippet is

```
<div data-bind="foreach: $root.bookArr1" >
    <p> Which book says <span data-bind="text: $data.bookQoute"></span>.</p>
    <p><select data-bind="options: $root.bookArr, value: answer, optionsText: 'bookName', uniqueName: true"></select></p>           
</div>
```

The viewmodel is below (snippet only)

```
this.firstName = ko.observable();
this.lastName = ko.observable();
this.answer = ko.observable();

this.bookQoutes = ([ 
    { bookQoute: "Curiouser and curiouser!", bookName: "Alice in wonderland" },
    { bookQoute: "Standard (iceream)", bookName: "PQR" },
    { bookQoute: "Standard (honey)", bookName: "LMY" },
    { bookQoute: "Standard (lemon)", bookName: "JND" }
]);

this.bookArr1 = ko.observableArray( this.bookQoutes );

this.bookArr = ko.observableArray( this.bookQoutes );
```

My problem is that when I remove value : answer from my html, this runs fine and displays the four lines with dropdown below it.

But when I add value: answer, I get the following exception

```
Unable to parse bindings. Message: ReferenceError: answer is not defined; 
Bindings value: options: $root.bookArr, value: answer, optionsText: 'bookName', uniqueName: true
```

Can anyone please point out what I am doing wrong here. I have looked up everywhere but I cannot seem to find a solution to this problem.

Thanks
Titash

Comment: Please mark Tom's answer as "accepted".  He took the time to answer your question and solve your problem, please give him the credit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify value: $root.answer because the binding context at that point is the current instance of a bookQoute, not the root, so Knockout will be looking for the answer property on bookQoute and not finding it.

Comment: +1. The `foreach` binding creates a new binding context. So, unless you explicitly state otherwise (i.e. using `$root` as outlined here), knockout will do any property lookups against the current context, which is, in this case, `$root.bookArr1` (not on `bookQuote` as stated in the answer)

Comment: Thanks all. This worked like a charm and I learnt quite a bit. Appreciate this community support.

Comment: Hope you're enjoying Knockout, Titash. Another cool thing about Knockout's binding of selects is that you can source the "options" from any object, not just the view model where your selected value gets saved - which means you can reuse data in an efficient way. For example, if you had a list of 200 products, you could add that array on an object called "referenceViewModel", and then have 10 customers each bound to their own CustomerViewModel where "FavouriteProductID" is defined on CustomerViewModel but the options are all defined as "options: referenceViewModel.products". I do this a lot.

Comment: Hi Tom, Thanks. Yes I am loving KO! I have never been as excited about a single tech in the recent past, as I am with KO - because of the possibilities it opens. There is a slight learning curve ofcourse, but I feel its worth the effort. Thanks for the tip as well. Regards.

Comment: Hi Tom, I am sorry but I seem to have run into another problem. Using $root.answer as my value, I see in my console.log that it sends [object Object] as the observable's (this.answer) state. 

Also, every select in the loop is changing its value, when I click on any one of them. So if there are 4 qoutes, and 4 select options, when I choose the first one, the remaining three also change to that value. The other three should be independent of each other.

Would appreciate help or if you could point me to any doc that I should read more to understand. Thanks.

Comment: Ah OK, yes, every question needs to bind back to its own answer property. There are lots of ways you could structure this depending on your problem's scope, but this fiddle demonstrates one simple way: http://jsfiddle.net/aUwx9/52/ ko.utils.arrayMap is taking each instance of a bookquote and using it to construct an instance of a QuestionVM, and that is what gets bound in an ObservableArray. When displaying the answers in the button click handler, I'm calling .answer() with brackets because an observable is a function, and this executes it to return the value. Does that work for you?

Comment: Thanks Tom! Sorry I just saw this response. 

I solved this problem by doing the whole thing all over again and referring to the shopping cart example's view model. Its very close to how you have outlined it above. I am going to make a fiddle for this one, and request you (and others) to take a look and give me opinions about it, and for the benefit of others who look for answers. 

But thanks once again for taking time out to explain.